# Read files of a line in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a 1000 files named coord_1.xvg, coord_2.xvg and so on. I have written a program that reads the second column of each of these files and gives me the output on the if else condition that I have provided. It prints a list of N's followed by either P or R depending on whichever is obtained first and stops.

```
    from pathlib import Path
    for file in Path("/home/abc/xyz/coord/").rglob("*.xvg"):
        with file.open("r") as f:
            for i, line in enumerate(file):
                if i < 22:
                    continue
                line = line.strip().split()
                if float(line[1]) >= 9.5:
                    print("P")
                break

                elif float(line[1]) <= 5.9:
                    print("R")
                break
                else:
                    print("N")
```

I want to read these files and print the value in the first column corresponding to the output P or R as the output along with P or R. Basically, I need to find the line at which the reading of this file had stopped and extract the value corresponding to it.

Comment: Should those break statements be under the ifs? Otherwise you have dead code here

Comment: No, it's fine, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable outside the loop, that you can set to `i` when your condition is met.

```
from pathlib import Path
stopped = 0
for file in Path("/home/abc/xyz/coord/").rglob("*.xvg"):
    with file.open("r") as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(file):
            if i < 22:
                continue
            line = line.strip().split()
            if float(line[1]) >= 9.5:
                print("P")
                stopped = i
            break

            elif float(line[1]) <= 5.9:
                print("R")
                stopped = i
            break
            else:
                print("N")
```

Also, if I am understanding correctly, your `break` statements should be indented to be inside the `if` and `elif` blocks

Let me know if you have any questions.